# JavaFX Custom Bindings not working

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I came across this issue on a larger scale application where some custom bindings weren't being updated when the value of the source property changed.

I managed to write a simple class to replicate this issue and I really don't get why this happens. Here's a quick test that replicates the problem:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

public class TestingBindingsFx {

  private final ObjectProperty<MyEvent> objectProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<MyEvent>(this, "objectProperty");
  private final BooleanProperty booleanProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "booleanProperty");

  private ObjectBinding<MyEvent> bindingObj;
  private BooleanBinding bindingBool;

  public TestingBindingsFx(ObjectProperty<String> selection) {
    setupBindings(selection);
  }

  private void setupBindings(ObjectProperty<String> selection) {
    bindingObj = createObjectBinding(selection);
    bindingBool = createBooleanBinding(selection);
    objectProperty.bind(bindingObj);
    booleanProperty.bind(bindingBool);
  }

  private static ObjectBinding<MyEvent> createObjectBinding(ObjectProperty<String> selection) {
    return new ObjectBinding<MyEvent>() {
      {
        super.bind(selection);
      }

      @Override
      protected MyEvent computeValue() {
        System.out.println("createObjectBinding called");
        MyEvent ve = selection.get() == null ? MyEvent.EVENT1
            : MyEvent.EVENT2;
        return ve;
      }
    };
  }

  private static BooleanBinding createBooleanBinding(ObjectProperty<String> selection) {
    return new BooleanBinding() {
      {
        super.bind(selection);
      }

      @Override
      protected boolean computeValue() {
        System.out.println("createBooleanBinding called");
        return selection.get() == null ? true : false;
      }
    };
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjClass objclass = new ObjClass();
    System.out.println("Instantiating TestingBindingsFx...");
    TestingBindingsFx fx = new TestingBindingsFx(objclass.selection);

    objclass.selection.addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
      @Override
      public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        System.out.println("changed " + oldValue + "->" + newValue);
      }
    });

    System.out.println("Changing selection property values...");
    objclass.selection.set("Test 1");
    objclass.selection.set("Test 2");
  }

  enum MyEvent {
    EVENT1,
    EVENT2;
  }

  static class ObjClass {
    public final ObjectProperty<String> selection = new SimpleObjectProperty<String>(this, "selection");
  }
}
```

So after running this I see:

> ```
> Instantiating TestingBindingsFx...
> createObjectBinding called
> createBooleanBinding called
> Changing selection property values...
> changed null->Test 1
> changed Test 1->Test 2
> ```

**When I expected to see something like:**

> ```
> Instantiating TestingBindingsFx...
> createObjectBinding called
> createBooleanBinding called
> Changing selection property values...
> changed null->Test 1
> createObjectBinding called
> createBooleanBinding called
> changed Test 1->Test 2
> createObjectBinding called
> createBooleanBinding called
> ```

The `ChangeListener` is working as expected (just put it there for verification purposes) and it's getting called every time I change the value of the selection property.

But the custom bindings are never updated after the first time and looking at the code I can't understand why. At first I thought it could be related with weak references, but I even turned the binding objects into class level variables and yet no change.

I feel that I might be missing something crucial here, but after 2 hours of looking at this code I just can't see why.
On my actual application it's even more strange since one of the custom bindings actually work fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because JavaFX is lazy, seriously.

If a dependency is invalidated, a binding is marked as invalid and `InvalidationListener`s are notified of a potential change. Unless you add `ChangeListener`s or use `get` to retrieve the value, the `computeValue` method is never used, since there is "no one who wants to know about the new value". This can improve performance.

Binding properties is done using a `InvalidationListener` and the properties are also refreshed lazily.

You could e.g. add change listeners to the properties to force recalculation of values every time the binding is invalidated:

```java
private void setupBindings(ObjectProperty<String> selection) {
    bindingObj = createObjectBinding(selection);
    bindingBool = createBooleanBinding(selection);
    objectProperty.bind(bindingObj);
    booleanProperty.bind(bindingBool);

    objectProperty.addListener((a,b,c)-> {});
    booleanProperty.addListener((a,b,c)-> {});
}
```

Comment: Bingo, that was it! I knew I was missing something simple, I was so focused on the computeValue not being called that completely forgot about the lazyness nature of the bindings. I don't need to force recalculation, lazyness is perfectly fine I was simply missing to read the target properties back on my test code after changing the source property values. Thanks for the quick answer.